# Image from Glide only loaded at second click on Google Maps marker

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-glide

I have this code to import an image to my custom WindowInfoAdapter for Google Maps markers.

```
override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {
    // 1rst - Get tag
    val pointOfInterest = marker.tag as? PointOfInterest ?: return null

    // 2nd - Inflate view and set values

    window.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.marker_title).text = pointOfInterest.title

    val image = window.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.marker_image)
    Glide
        .with(context)
        .load(pointOfInterest.imageUrl)
        .addListener(object : RequestListener<Drawable>{
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                Log.d("glide","Error loading the image url")
                return false
            }
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                Log.d("glide","Loaded")
                Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed({
                    if (marker.isInfoWindowShown) {
                        marker.showInfoWindow()
                    }
                }, 100)

                return false
            }

        })
        .into(image)

    return window
}
```

The problem is that the first time I click on a marker, the image is not loaded and the override methods of the add listener method are not used. When I click in another marker then all the images are loaded. How can I solve this bug?